# get netcdf variable start offset

Tags: java, netcdf

I am using netcdf-java to access netcdf files and variables. I wonder how I can get each variable's start offset and seek to that offset directly. The following is my current code which I get the variables from the method findVariable

```
NcHdfsRaf raf = new NcHdfsRaf(file, job.getConfiguration());
NetcdfFile ncfile = WRFFile.openFile(raf, path.toString()); 
Variable timesVar = ncfile.findVariable("Temperature");
```

Comment: I want to get this kind of API because the Netcdf files I am handling is on Hadoop Distributed File System - HDFS and is distributed in multiple blocks in multiple nodes. I am thinking it would be more efficient if I can identify which block the variables considered are in and read only that block on one node instead of reading the whole file from multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Why do you want that? It's probably a terrible idea. You already have an interface for reading data, and that interface insulates you from any underlying file format changes.  Furthermore, remember that netcdf is a portable file format: if you read 1000 bytes from a given offset, those bytes might not be what you expect -- the library will deal with endian conversions and any possible type conversions that must happen.

With all that out of the way, if for some goofy reason you wanted to get the offset, I don't see anything in the Java class that will let you do that:

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/javadoc/ucar/nc2/Variable.html

If you were doing this in the C library, underneath the public API, you could peek at types of NC_Var: the 'begin' member of the struct is where data begins:

https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/blob/master/include/nc3internal.h#L159